# How to use web.config with two domains

Tags: web-config

I have this cenario:

1. In my principal domain i have my blog under permalink wordpress
2. In an folder /xyz i have an other domain abc.com.br pointed.

How to construct rules to both.

This is my actualy web.config. only work with blog.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard"  stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: If they're two instances of the application then presumably you'd have two separate `web.config` files.  A configuration file is specifically for maintaining instance-specific or environment-specific values.

Comment: but there is a way to use same application, using single web.config?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, I thought there were two separate instances of the application.  Maybe you can describe some scenarios in more detail in the question?